# Redefinition of module 'Realm'

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, realm

I working on an Objective c project, and trying to get it to work with Swift too.
I've allready have been throw this process in the past, but did'nt get this error.

After adding `use_framworks` to my podfile, and replacing all "" imports with <> or @import, I'm getting this error:

Redefinition of module `Realm`
In the `module.modulemap` file:

```
framework module Realm { //This is the line the error is on
    umbrella header "Realm.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }

    explicit module Private {
        header "RLMAccessor.h"
        header "RLMArray_Private.h"
        header "RLMListBase.h"
        header "RLMMigration_Private.h"
        header "RLMObjectSchema_Private.h"
        header "RLMObjectStore.h"
        header "RLMObject_Private.h"
        header "RLMOptionalBase.h"
        header "RLMProperty_Private.h"
        header "RLMRealmConfiguration_Private.h"
        header "RLMRealm_Private.h"
        header "RLMResults_Private.h"
        header "RLMSchema_Private.h"
    }

    explicit module Dynamic {
        header "RLMRealm_Dynamic.h"
        header "RLMObjectBase_Dynamic.h"
    }
}
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Use the version 1.0.0 maybe helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the `use_frameworks!` keyword in CocoaPods if you're bringing in a dependency that uses Swift code. Is that what you're doing?

If you're also starting to access Realm code from a Swift class, make sure you've included the `Swift/RLMSupport.swift` bridging header as well.

Aside from that, looking at the CocoaPods issue where [this sort of issue was reported](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3886), you should also make sure that you've absolutely removed all traces of `#import ""` everywhere.

If that still doesn't work for you, then you might need to add some more information to your question about how your project is set up with regards to how it uses both Objective-C and Swift, and what your podfile looks like.

Comment: Thank you for your time, Yes I've tried to insert Swift to and Objective c project, and at the end it was just a matter of really going throw every import and checking it imports with <> in cast its static library, and cleaning every few minutes, the build and driven data, because I found Xcode has some cach between sessions.